# Is proof that $U = \{v \in V: \phi(v)=0\text{ for every } v \in U^0\}$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

This problem stems from Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" and I would like to verify if this proof is correct:

$Problem$:

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $U$is a subspace of V. Show that
$$U = \{v \in V: \phi(v)=0\text{ for every } v \in U^0\}$$

$Proof$:

Assume that the list $u_1, ..., u_m$ is a basis of $U$. Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$ this list can be extended to a basis of $V$ as $u_1, ..., u_m, u_{m+1}, ... u_n$. Hence, any $v \in V$can be written as
$$v=a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_mu_m + a_{m+1}u_{m+1} + \cdots + a_nu_n$$

for $a_1, ..., a_m, a_{m+1}, ..., a_n \in F$. Now assume that $\phi \in U^0$. Then
$$\phi(u_i) = 0$$

for $i = 1, ..., m$. However, $\phi(v)\neq 0$ if some $u_{m+1}, ..., u_n \neq0$ (because $u_{m+1}, ..., u_n \notin U$). This is only true if all $u_{m+1}, ..., u_n = 0$. Then
$$v = a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_mu_m = span(u_1, ..., u_m) = U$$

as desired.

Comment: What are $\phi$ and $U^0$? Also, the expression $$\{v\in V: \phi(v)=0\text{ for every } v\in U^0\}$$ is nonsensical. Is $v$ in $V$ or is it in $U^0$?

Comment: @5xum, being familiar with the text at hand, $U^0$ is the annihilator of $U$ in $V^*$ and so $\phi$ is just some functional in the annihilator.

Comment: Basis elements canot be $0$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As memerson said: $U^0$ is the annihilator of $U$. $\phi$ represents a linear functional in $V'$, where $V'$ is the dual space of $V$. And yes, $v$ is in $V$. @Kavi: any suggestion how to do the proof differently?

Comment: I think I got it, I have to prove that the coefficients $a_{m+1}, ..., a_{n}=0$. Of course a basis element cannot be $0$ ... Thanks for the hint.